# Flutter Hero Widget Not Transitioning Between Widget And Dialog

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a Square tile with and Icon, Text and a container as background and I also have a function 'showCustomDialog' which baisically is the showDialog but with some of my own adjustments, the custom dialog has an Icon, Text, 2 Fields, 1 Button and a Container as background. the Dialog is triggered when i click on the tile and i have passed 3 hero tags, bg, icon and text which are supposed to transition upon clicking the squaretile but for some reason aren't, there is no error message.

### tile.dart

This is the tile which, upon clicking, should transition it's background, text and icon to the

---

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class SquareTile extends StatelessWidget {
  Icon icon;
  String text = '';
  String bgTag;
  String iconTag;
  String textTag;
  SquareTile({
    required this.icon,
    required this.text,
    required this.bgTag,
    required this.iconTag,
    required this.textTag,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Hero(
          tag: bgTag,
          child: Material(
            type: MaterialType.transparency,
            child: Container(
              width: 300,
              height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[100],
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 10,
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            child: Hero(
              tag: iconTag,
              child: Material(type: MaterialType.transparency, child: icon),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 80,
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 150,
            child: Center(
              child: Hero(
                tag: textTag,
                child: Material(
                  type: MaterialType.transparency,
                  child: Text(
                    text,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

---

### showCustomDialog()

Dialog which appears when I click the SquareTile()

---

```dart
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smooth_like_flutter/components/service_field.dart';

void showCustomDialog(
  BuildContext context,
  Icon icon,
  String title,
  String rates,
  String bgTag,
  String iconTag,
  String textTag,
) {
  final quantityController = TextEditingController();
  final linkController = TextEditingController();
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  child: BackdropFilter(
                    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Hero(
                  tag: bgTag,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 400,
                    width: 280,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 1.5),
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                        borderRadius:
                            const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 350),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Hero(
                        tag: iconTag,
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.group_rounded,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          size: 40,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Hero(
                        tag: textTag,
                        child: Material(
                          type: MaterialType.transparency,
                          child: Text(
                            title,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        rates,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      MyServiceField(
                        type: TextInputType.number,
                        controller: quantityController,
                        hint: 'Quantity',
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      MyServiceField(
                        type: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        controller: linkController,
                        hint: 'Link',
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 35,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 200,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Place Order',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      });
}
```

---

and finally

### instagram.dart

where the tile is initialized

---

```dart
SizedBox(
            height: 400,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    showCustomDialog(
                      context,
                      const Icon(Icons.group_rounded),
                      'Followers',
                      '100 -> 100',
                      'followers_bg',
                      'followers-icon',
                      'followers-text',
                    );
                  },
                  child: SquareTile(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.group_rounded),
                      text: 'Followers',
                      bgTag: 'followers_bg',
                      iconTag: 'followers-icon',
                      textTag: 'follwers-text'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

---

I have tried changing their tags to match each other but it isnt working for some reason